# How to import QtQuick components

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I want to use some QML elements from module Qt Components (or something like that) and I don't know how to import them in QML file. QtCreator hasn't code completion in this case, but I remember, there was a line like:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
```

Files, which I want to import, there are in directory `~/Qt5.0.1/Tools/QtCreator/lib/qtcreator/qtcomponents` (i.e. ScrollArea.qml, TableColumn.qml, ButtonRow.qml, TableView.qml, TextArea.qml etc.)

I use QtQuick 1.1.

Comment: AFAIK QtQuick Controls is only supported with QtQuick 2.

Comment: @jturcotte: Although these files contain `import Qt Quick 1.0`, `import Qt 4.7`? Maybe this module isn't called "Controls", I want to import files from `qtcomponents` folder.

Comment: Yes you're right, considering that those files seem to be internal QML files for QtCreator itself, you might be able to import them using QDeclarativeEngine::addImportPath, or through the QML_IMPORT_PATH environment variable.

Comment: Another option is to get a copy of those components from the qt4 branch at https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/d41f99efdb99b337761f0575ad28434f6aaa07ba and get this module compiled and installed beside your application. My real suggestion would be to switch to QtQuick2 if possible though :)

Comment: Thanks, I added `QML_IMPORT_PATH` to .pro file and it works.